# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for setTorchMode

Tags: java, android, multithreading, illegalargumentexception, flashlight

I see a lot of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Google Play crash reports without a specific line of my App code. I assume it is when setting torch of flashlight because I see that it is associated with CameraManager.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher (LoadedApk.java:793)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1200)
      at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$3.run (CameraManager.java:1266)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Main Activity:

```
FlashLight flashLight;

flashLight = new FlashLightApi23(context,alarmManagement, mAppSettings, anAlarmIsActive());
Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (flashLight.flashSupportingCameras.size() > 0) {
        mAppSettings.flashLightCameraId = ((FlashLightInfo) flashLight.flashSupportingCameras.get(0)).cameraId;
    } else {
        mFlashLight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                setFlashLight(context, mAppSettings.flashLightCameraId, true);
                ...
            }
    }
}



public void setFlashLight(final Context context, final String cameraId, final boolean on) {
        String status="off";
        if (on)
            status="on";
        addLog(context,"","setFlashLight: "+status);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                flashLight.setFlashLight(context, cameraId, on, alarmManagement, mAppSettings, anAlarmIsActive());
            }
        });
    }
```

Flashlight Class:

```
    public class FlashLightApi23 extends FlashLight {
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    @TargetApi(23)
    public FlashLightApi23(Context context, AlarmManagement alarmManagement, AppSettings appSettings, boolean alarmActive) {
        cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        flashSupportingCameras=getFlashSupportingCameras(context,alarmManagement,appSettings,alarmActive);
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private ArrayList<FlashLightInfo> getFlashSupportingCameras(Context context, AlarmManagement alarmManagement, AppSettings appSettings, boolean alarmActive){
        ArrayList<FlashLightInfo> result = new ArrayList<FlashLightInfo>();
        try {
            String[] cameraIdList = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            for (int i=0;i<cameraIdList.length;i++) {
                CameraCharacteristics mCameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIdList[i]);
                Boolean flashInfoAvailable=mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                if (flashInfoAvailable!=null && flashInfoAvailable.booleanValue()) {
                    FlashLightInfo flashLightInfo=new FlashLightInfo();
                    flashLightInfo.cameraId=cameraIdList[i];
                    Integer lensFacing=mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                    if (lensFacing!=null) {
                        flashLightInfo.lensFacing = lensFacing.intValue();
                        switch (flashLightInfo.lensFacing) {
                            case CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT:
                                flashLightInfo.cameraName = context.getString(R.string.front);
                                break;
                            case CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK:
                                flashLightInfo.cameraName = context.getString(R.string.Back);
                                break;
                            case CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL:
                                flashLightInfo.cameraName = context.getString(R.string.external);
                                break;
                        }
                        if (flashLightInfo.lensFacing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                            result.add(0, flashLightInfo);
                        else
                            result.add(flashLightInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            Tools.debugLogger.addLog(context,"flash CameraAccessException:",e.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Tools.debugLogger.addLog(context,"flash RuntimeException:",e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    boolean torchModeOn=false;

        @TargetApi(23)
    public void setFlashLight(Context context, String cameraId, boolean on, AlarmManagement alarmManagement, AppSettings appSettings, boolean alarmActive) {
        try {
            Tools.debugLogger.addLog(context, "flash", " setFlashLight cameraId: " + cameraId);
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, on);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            if (!alarmActive)
                Tools.showMessage(e.getMessage(),context);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Tools.showMessage(e.getMessage(),context);
        }
    }
}
```

It could be related to thread issues. I have an extra thread running while my activity is shown which takes care of starting and stopping an alarm (it is an alarm app). I had to move setFlashLight into runOnUiThread in the past because I got "run from wrong Thread" issues. Maybe the issure is not there any more.

Is it safe to put setFlashLight out of runOnUiThread? Also it seems to take a long time to set flash light on some devices.

How to find out cause of IllegalArgumentException? Why is there no text in Android console explaining what kind of IllegalArgument it is? I get this crash on many devices and none write a line of explanation.

Strange also that I am catching all Exceptions and still IllegalArgument is thrown.